# What does that $$var mean?

Tags: function, perl, variables

Firstly, I am beginner in Perl. I would like to know what does this code mean.

```
sub function
{
    my $var1 = shift;
    my $var2 = shift;

    if ($$var1)
    {
        #code
    }
    else
    {
        #code
    }
}
```

I know that it is a function, and var1 is first argument of function and var2 is the second argument. But what does mean that $$ in if statement?

**So it means that $var1 is hash?**

Comment: No. It doesn't mean that `$var1` is a hash. There are no hash lookup brackets. It means that `$var1` is a reference to a scalar.

Comment: @DaveCross make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$var1` is short for `${ $var1 }`.

`$NAME` and `$BLOCK` are the syntax for acccessing a *scalar*, not a hash.

`$NAME` access a variable directly.

`$BLOCK` access a variable indirectly, via a reference.

Therefore,

- `$var1` is a scalar.
- `$var1` is expected to to contain a reference to a scalar (e.g. `$var1 = \$var2;`)

Note that it's really weird to use references to scalars (as this sub does).